# adding and imposition image on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want add option to my image customize If I click add art I want add small picture from popup and this is work but I don't is see on image. In my script already have addition picture before div with image and after div.

http://finance.usermd.net/customizer/index.html

```
$(function() {
    $("#img-0").click(function () {

        $("<div src='art/art1.png' id='img-add-0'></div>").insertBefore('.img-board').draggable();
    });

    $("#img-1").click(function () {
        $('.image').append("<div src='art/art2.png' id='img-add-0'></div>").draggable();
    });
    $("#img-2").click(function () {
        $('.image').append("<div src='art/art3.png' id='img-add-0'></div>").draggable();
    });
    $('#img-0').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });
    $('#img-1').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });
    $('#img-2').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });
    $('#testdragable').draggable();
})
```

css

```
.popup-box {
    background: #265a88;
}

#img-add-0 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
#img-2 {
    background-color: #265a88;
}
```

Comment: can you include your code in your question?

Comment: can you include the html and css too?

Comment: `<div src='art/art2.png' id='img-add-0'></div>`  - don't you want to use an `img` tag here ;-)